# Deleting a record from Gridview with ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a gridview that binds its rows from an objects method:

public DataSet GetObjects()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var source = from p in CommentsList
                 select new { p.CommentID, p.Img, p.Name, p.Comment };

```
dt.Columns.Add("CommentsID");
dt.Columns.Add("Img");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Comment");

foreach (var item in source)
{



    DataRow userDetailsRow=dt.NewRow();
    userDetailsRow["Img"] = item.Img;
    userDetailsRow["Name"] = item.Name;

    DataRow commentsID = dt.NewRow();
    userDetailsRow["CommentsID"] = item.CommentID;

    DataRow comments = dt.NewRow();
    userDetailsRow["Comment"] = item.Comment;
    dt.Rows.Add(userDetailsRow);
    //dt.Rows.Add(comments);
}
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
return ds;
```

}
My delete method. Should receive the commentsID to delete it from the database and then rebind the Gridview.. But how? do i pass the CommentsID from the gridview to this method
public void RemoveComment(int CommentsID)
{
}

GridViews Two templates:

```
 <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="imgName" runat="server"  imageUrl='<%# Bind("Img") %>'></asp:Image><br />
                            <asp:Hyperlink ID="hyperLink" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' ></asp:Hyperlink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

Now, I want to delete a row, how do I do that? I know that DataKeyNames exist..but how do I set the commentsID as my dataKeyNames, and how do i delete  a record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `Delete method` to the objectDataSource and it will be very simple...e.g.

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server" DeleteMethod="RemoveComment" SelectMethod="GetCityByStateID" TypeName="">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CommentsID" Type="Int32" />
         </DeleteParameters>
          <SelectParameters>
          </SelectParameters>
  </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Whenever the Gridview Delete button is hit this will automatically fire this method and delete the record.

Comment: I know I can. But doesnt the delete method need some parameter to take... to know what to delete. i set in the datakeynames of the gridview CommentsID.. But how can I pass the CommentsID key to delete method? to delete the record?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that, It will automatically picked. Just use it and try.

Comment: Could you see if the code , i updated above is correct. Does it delete remember the collection that i put into memory and form that collection in the dataset, it passes me the key, which i need to apply in my method..and come up with an sql statement to delete the comment?

Comment: ObjectDataSource Delete method will automatically pick the DataKeyName. Your Delete Method should take one parameter as int that is commentId.

Comment: So everything above is right.. a parameter will be passed.. and the information is retreived from the dataset?

Comment: yes, ObjectDataSource is very smart, whenever row is deleted, it will automatically rebind the gridview. I would suggest you to read some article about ObjectDataSource. Very smart Control!!!